# A sample historical online trading data to download?

Tags: data-request, finance

I am working a part time project (a hobby project) and I am looking for some data dump for historical online trading data. By trading data I mean the online trade that goes on in like Wall street and other financial markets. I tried to look for such a data but all I could find was stock data which is not what I am looking for.

Does anyone know from where can I download(preferably as a csv or excel format data) a sample of such online trading data?

Answer (score 1):

Individual trades will come anonymized from a broker directly, and aren't available unless you use that broker, or pay for a terminal (like Bloomberg).

Consider using cryptocurrency transactions, which are part of the public ledger

https://blockchain.info/blocks

has data on individual transactions

[image]

([source of screenshot](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000000008a62772b348871f2f213f47d5cf1e9c0550d15df851371))

The above website also offers an [API](https://blockchain.info/api) to get the data